# Problems with my datagridview - getting error

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a desktop project, C#, however I have problems working with datagridview, I want to make some fields invisible and give a headText on others, but an error message appears and the same code I use in another form and it works perfectly.

I tried instead to work with this table, work with others but the error is the same!

```
private void NomearDgv()
{
    dgvProduto.Columns [1].HeaderText = "Nome";
    dgvProduto.Columns [2].HeaderText = "Código de barra";
    dgvProduto.Columns [3].HeaderText = "Iva liquidado";
    dgvProduto.Columns [4].HeaderText = "Iva suportado";
    dgvProduto.Columns [8].HeaderText = "Categoria";
    dgvProduto.Columns [9].HeaderText = "Unidade";
    dgvProduto.Columns [10].HeaderText = "Tipo";
    dgvProduto.Columns [11].HeaderText = "Referência";
    dgvProduto.Columns [0].Visible = false;
    dgvProduto.Columns [5].Visible = false;
    dgvProduto.Columns [6].Visible = false;
    dgvProduto.Columns [7].Visible = false;
    dgvProduto.Columns [12].Visible = false;
    dgvProduto.Columns [13].Visible = false;
    dgvProduto.Columns [14].Visible = false;
    dgvProduto.Columns [15].Visible = false;
}
```

The error is:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'The index was out of range. Must be non-negative and smaller than collection size. Parameter Name: index '

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on [localized site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) or translated into english.

Answer (score -2):

Remember that the column index starts with zero, so if you want to get the first column value, it is not index 1 but 0. So your code would look like:

```
    dgvProduto.Columns [0].HeaderText = "Nome";
    dgvProduto.Columns [1].HeaderText = "Código de barra";
    dgvProduto.Columns [2].HeaderText = "Iva liquidado";
    dgvProduto.Columns [3].HeaderText = "Iva suportado";
    dgvProduto.Columns [4].HeaderText = "Categoria";
    dgvProduto.Columns [5].HeaderText = "Unidade";
    dgvProduto.Columns [6].HeaderText = "Tipo";
    dgvProduto.Columns [7].HeaderText = "Referência";
```

Comment: Please post only in English :)

Comment: The mistake is the same! it does not resolve the problem

Comment: this.dgvProduto.Columns.Add(ColumnName, HeaderText);

Comment: It works, but I bring the information from database and so I add more fields to datagriedview and not rename itself.